# Remove a specific letter from a specific line in a file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

This is probably a duplicate, but I couldn't find my answer anywhere.

I have a text file and I want to remove a specific character from a specific line.

Here's one example:

```
#textfile.txt


Hey!
1234/
How are you//?
9/23r
```

How can I remove the slash from the second line?

The output should be:

```
#textfile.txt


Hey!
1234
How are you//?
9/23r
```

I've got no code and no clue on how to do this.

I run python 2.7.14 on Debian.

Comment: "*I've got no code*", then you should go and get some. This is a fairly easy thing to implement. You can start here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: whats special about the "specific character from a specific line" that you wanna remove?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the file line by line and identify the line you want to modify. Then identify the index/location of the character you want to modify(remove).
Replace it with blank and write the text line by line into the file.

```
#opeing the .txt file
fp = open("data.txt", "r")
#reading text line by line
text= fp.readlines()
#searching for character to remove
char = text[1][-2]
#removing the character by replacing it with blank
text[1] = text[1].replace(char, "")

#opeing the file in write mode
fw = open("data.txt", "w") 
#writing lines one by one
for lines in text:
   fw.write(lines)
#closing the file
fw.close()
```

Comment: It works nice. But can you explain me the index you used a little more?

Comment: So, basically in your file, every line has a next line ('\n') character at the end. In Python, -1 is the index of the last character but the character that you want to remove is a slash that comes just before the last character which makes its index as -2. So her, text[1] is the second line and text[1][-2] is that slash that you want to remove.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution is to read in the *entire* file, find the line that you want to change, change it, and write out *all* of the content again:

```
filename = 'textfile.txt'
original = '1234/'
replacement = '1234'
# Open file for reading and read all lines into a list
with open('textfile.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
# Find the line number (index) of the original string
index = lines.index(original + '\n')
# Replace this element of the list
lines[index] = replacement + '\n'
# Write out the modified lines to disk
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```